# Show alert() if no radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, radio-button

After click the button "Delete", How to display an alert if none of radio button is selected. My html form

```
<form name="Action" method="post" action="RequestAction">
                    <table width="800px" cellpadding="5" style="color:black; border-top:1px solid #ccc;" border="0">
                    </table>
                    <div id="container">
                    <div id="demo_jui">
                    <table id="requestList" class="display" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="font-size:12px;" >
                    <thead id="headed">
                        <tr>
                            <th  align="center" title="Employee">Employee</th>
                            <th  align="center" title="Number of Days">Number of Days</th>
                            <th  align="center" title="Start Date">Start Date</th>
                            <th  align="center" title="End Date">End Date</th>
                            <th  align="center" title="Leave Type">Leave Type</th>
                            <th  align="center" title="Remark">Remark</th>
                            <th  align="center">Approve</th>
                            <th  align="center">Reject</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                    </table>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                        <table>                 
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding-left:0px;" colspan="3">
                                <a href="#"><img src="images/Submit.png" style="border:none;" onClick="javascript:Go()"
                                onmouseover="this.src='images/Submit_Hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/Submit.png'"/></a>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <a href="#"><img src="images/Reset.png" style="border:none;" onClick="javascript:clearForm()"
                                onmouseover="this.src='images/Reset_Hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/Reset.png'"/></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
```

The radio button value will be retrieved in table. When I test it, if click submit button without select any radio button, i will get error

In function Go(), is the way validate radio button correct? Thank you

```
function Go() {
                if( $('form[name=Action] input[name=statusList]:checked').length == 0)
                {
                    $('form[name=Action]').submit();
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Please select at least one to delete");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Your HTML doesn't appear to have any checkbox or inputs at all. Also, your JavaScript appears to be backwards in that your conditional is only submitting when there are NO checked inputs. Also, the Java and exception stack trace are not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the check for "checked" status doesn't work?

```
//read value of radio button
alert($("input[name='radio-button-group']:checked").val());

//get bool, if radio button is checked
alert(typeof $("input[name='radio-button-group']:checked").val() != 'undefined');
```

Source (german): http://mabraham.de/jquery-radio-buttons-auslesen-und-manipulieren/

Answer (score 1):

use the below snippet

```
var IsChecked = $('take id or classname of radiogroup').is(':checked');

if(!IsChecked)
{
alert("select some thing");
}
```

Comment: i test it with

`
var IsChecked = $('form[name=Action] input[name=statusList]').is(':checked');
   function Go() {
       if( !IsChecked)
       {
        alert("Please select at least one to delete");        
       }
       else
       {
        $('form[name=Action]').submit();
       }
   }
`

however, it keep prompt alert whenever radio button is selected or not

Comment: please debug it in firebug and let me know what is the value u are getting in to IsChecked and how the rest code behave i mean entering in to if block and all........i think u are missing out something in getting particular element what is the id or class name u r having